# Can we burninate the [backend] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Can we send the [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backend) tag back where it came from?

I think the tag is too generic to be helpful, and the actual language tags it's often accompanied with are enough to categorize the questions it is applied to.

The tag's description is

> Defines a component in a logical separation of an application.

Which is pretty generic. There are 4k questions tagged with [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backend), but are also tagged with the language they are associated with, so removing the tag from those questions en masse shouldn't negatively affect the question. I haven't seen any positively received questions with backend only as a tag, just stuff like this: *[What should I use for back-end? Which one is best for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334717/what-is-best-for-backend)*

Comment: There is also the [frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/frontend/info) tag. I think both should be burninated.

Comment: Can you please evaluate that tag against the criteria for burnnation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination I

Comment: Well it's on topic, while not exactly the same in all contexts but it conveys similar concept, it's not crystal clear but I won't go as far as calling it ambiguous, and can add meaningful info. to the question, at least just looking at it in the context of tags. It's not the most helpful tag, but there are many more to go before this one IMHO.

Comment: @M-- well son, get to work https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request

Comment: One thing I agree with you on is that the tag's description was pretty useless, especially the user guidance - I've submitted an edit to improve that, which is under peer review now: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26920864

Answer (score 13):

Quoting the [criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) @rene linked:

> There are four preliminary tests that help identifying problematic tags:
>
> > 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> > 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> > 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> > 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
>
> A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for
> burnination. In any case, the ultimate criterion for burnination is
> whether the tag is actually causing harm

And I don't think the case against backend seems strong enough for burnination. It doesn't pass any of these with flying colors, but I think it minimally passes all four criteria, and for tag in the 4k range that seems sufficient. Keep in mind, per the above post failing just one is not sufficient to qualify for burnination.

My reasoning is as follows:

1. Yes, backend is a wide term, but it's not particularly ambiguous, and usefully describes the context in which a question is asked
2. Backend/frontend is certainly on-topic for SO
3. While by itself it's not a particularly useful tag, it does add some useful information. Using Python for frontend stuff is a very different usecase than using it for backend, for instance.
4. Again, "backend" has a pretty common conceptual meaning, even if the specifics of what it means in any given stack vary considerably, and the borders are a little fuzzy sometimes.

It's not the most useful tag, but I don't think it's causing harm, or even undue clutter, and is marginally useful.

Comment: "but I think it minimally passes all four criteria" if that were true, no ambiguous tag would ever be burninated. And yes, I disagree, it's an ambiguous tag, for the purposes of SO.

Comment: I was planning to write something similar, but you've conveyed my thoughts in a wonderful manner. If tags are ambiguous, then they should be disambiguated, if tags are harmful then they should be burninated.

Comment: I think "buzzwords" might need a different procedure. Because "backend" and "frontend" are buzzwords with no precise technical definition. In some specific context they might make sense, but in general terms they don't. Buzzwords are characterized by no existing clear and objective definition of what the term is actually about.